# Newly created NSManagedObject returns temporary objectID even after save

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Very simple situation. Not sure why it's causing an issue.

I have a view that creates a new NSManagedObject in a child  NSManagedObjectContext. When the user presses "done", it saves the child context, then it saves the parent context, then it posts a notification with the newly created object's objectID. In the main view controller, I respond to the notification and try to get the newly created object with `existingObjectWithID:error:`.

Problem is this fails because the objectID is temporary (I get a "Cocoa error 133000"). The saves to the two contexts are flawless: when I reload the app, I can see the entries I created. But at the time I need to get a reference to the new object, it fails.

Why does it give me a temporary object ID *after* I've already saved it?

Note: I have tried using `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:`, which works, but the permanent ID still fails when I try to use it to obtain the object.

Here's some code:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    if ([editorDoneNotification isEqualToString:kNOTIFICATION_OBJECTADDED]) {
        // save the temporary moc
        NSError* e;
        if (![self.tempContext save:&e]) { // this is always a successful save
            NSLog(@"Failed to save temporary managed object context: %@", [e localizedDescription]);
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database Error"
                                    message:@"Failed to add object."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }
    }
    NSError* e;
    if (![[[AMDataModel sharedDataModel] mainContext] save:&e]) { // this is also successful
        NSLog(@"Failed to save main managed object context: %@", [e localizedDescription]);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Database Error"
                                message:@"Failed to edit object."
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
    else
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:editorDoneNotification object:[self.editingObject objectID]]; 

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And this is how I respond to the notifications:

```
-(void)objectAdded:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (self.popoverController && [self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }

    NSManagedObjectID* newObjectID = (NSManagedObjectID*)(notification.object);
    NSError* error;
    AMObject* object = (AMObject*)[[[AMDataModel sharedDataModel] mainContext] existingObjectWithID:newObjectID error:&error]; // this is where the cocoa error 133000 happens
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Could not load new object in main managed object context.");
    }

    GMSMarker* m = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    m.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(object.latitudeValue, object.longitudeValue);
    m.userData = object;
    m.map = self.mapView;
    [self.markers addObject:m];
}

-(void)objectEdited:(NSNotification *)notification
{  
    NSManagedObjectID* editedObjectID = (NSManagedObjectID*)notification.object;
    NSError* error = nil;
    AMObject* object = (AMObject*)[[[AMDataModel sharedDataModel] mainContext] existingObjectWithID:editedObjectID error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error could not load edited object in main managed object context");
    }

    //update the UI based on edit

    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.popoverController = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the child does not get updated back from the parent MOC.  The parent MOC will update its own instance of the `NSManagedObject` with a permanent ID but that change will not be pushed down to the instance of that `NSManagedObject` belonging to the child MOC.

### Update 1

I do not use `-objectID` in this situation.  It has some uses but it is not a permanent uniqueID.  In a situation like this, I prefer to add my own uniqueID to the entity and then fetch it from the main context.

You could also just listen for the context save notifications or use an NSFetchedResultsController which will receive updates.

Comment: So in this scenario, what's the best way to get a reference to the newly created object in the parent MOC?

Comment: What identifier do you use?

Comment: I create my own globally unique IDs and store them in the objects.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried obtaining the permanent ID's for your objects? I've had success sharing `NSManagedObjectID`'s between contexts by calling

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.context obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[object1, object2]
                                     error:&error];
```

followed by my save method. I structure my contexts in such a way that there is an I/O context which is the parent to my 'read context' (context used for my main thread activity) which is the parent to my background task contexts. Save in this case propagates all the way up the chain.

Comment: Passing `nil` to error is a bad thing. It hides errors that leave you scratching your head. Always, always, always check the error.

Comment: 100% agree with Marcus - this was a quick snippet from memory. I've edited for completeness.

Comment: Yep. I did try getting permanent IDs (mentioned in my question). But the main context still couldn't get the object.

Comment: Oh... I think I realize my mistake: I was calling `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` *after* saving my context. I'll try the other way too.

Comment: @MarcusSZarra: `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` does just that.