# Why does existingObjectWithID return an managedObject with temporaryID after save?

Tags: core-data

Why with `existingObjectWithID` fetched managedObject's objectID is still temporary, after main managedObjectContext is saved?

```
var dmo: NSManagedObject? = nil                                    
dmo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(relationshipDescription.destinationEntity.name, inManagedObjectContext: mocIn) as? NSManagedObject

let success = temporaryContext.save(nil)                                    
Utility.managedObjectContext().performBlockAndWait({
    let kkk = Utility.managedObjectContext().save(nil)
})

println("isTemporaryID: \(dmo!.objectID.temporaryID)") // <- returns true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410456/newly-created-nsmanagedobject-returns-temporary-objectid-even-after-save?rq=1), that says:

> Because the child does not get updated back from the parent MOC. The parent MOC will update its own instance of the NSManagedObject with a permanent ID but that change will not be pushed down to the instance of that NSManagedObject belonging to the child MOC.